# Django aggregate queried instances of foreign key

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    some fields

class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    order = models.ForiegnKey(Order)
    status = models.CharField(choices=['ORDERED', 'RECEIVED'])
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

**Using Django ORM, How do I aggregate (average) turn-around-times (TAT) into a single timespan?**
For example (pseudo-code):

```
Order0 (TAT=12 hours)
OrderStatus0: order=Order0, status=ORDERED, time=00:00 8/24/16
OrderStatus1: order=Order0, status=RECEIVED, time=12:00 8/24/16
Order1 (TAT=24 hours)
OrderStatus2: order=Order1, status=ORDERED, time=04:00 8/24/16
OrderStatus3: order=Order1, status=RECEIVED, time=04:00 8/25/16  
Average TAT = 18 hours
```

Pseudo-SQL would look like this:

```
Order
    tat = Average
        Subtract
            OrderStatus.status_time
                where status=RECEIVED
            OrderStatus.status_time
                where status=ORDERED
```

I have tried using a combination of `Aggregate()`, `Annotate()`, `F()`, `Q()`, `When`, and `Case`, but can't reach a solution because I need to need to query OrderStatus *inside of the aggregation*.

Here is a **non-working attempt:**

```
Order.objects.aggregate(
    Avg(
        F('order__orderstatus__status_time') - 
        F('order__orderstatus__status_time')))
```

FYI, I'm using Django 1.9 and Postgresql 9.3

Comment: How your OrderStatus model is defined makes things a bit complicated. Instead of looking a row at a time, one will need to perform an additional search for the corresponding row. It can be pulled off using raw SQL, but that involves multiple subqueries from the same table and aliased tables, two things that Django has very limited support for. You might want to implement "start" and "end" timestamps. The Django ORM code becomes a one-liner.

Comment: @WannabeCoder Thanks for your comment. I simplified some things - we have multiple more types of OrderStatus, which makes the time stamp fields not as effective. :/

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. If that is the case, then you will probably have to implement the calculations via Python, one `Order` object with its corresponding `OrderStatus` object at a time. You can do this using `Prefetch()` and some custom attributes in your `Order` model. I can give you sample code if you want.